# How to change data-attr when clone div

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have issue with cloning a div.

I have a div with `id=director-uploads1`. I want to append a div with `class=director-uploads-hidden` to it. I want to set newly cloned div with class `director-uploads-hidden` data-number to be with value #director-uploads1 data-number + 1.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function clone(){
     var number = $('#director-uploads1').attr('data-number');
     var director = $('.director-uploads-hidden').html();

                var clone = $('#director-uploads1').append(director)
                .find("*")
                .each(function() {
                   var name = $(this).attr('name');
                })
                .on('click', 'button.clone', clone);
    //I want to get $("#director-uploads1") attr data-number and to set data-number to the newly cloned div to be current value + 1
    //First I did it in this way $("#director-uploads1").attr('data-number', parseInt(number)+1);  but I don't want to change initial value of div, only value of the cloned div

    
    }
   $("button#add-director").on("click", clone);
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="director-uploads number" id="director-uploads1" data-number="0" data-changed="0">
   //some data
   </div>
 <div class="director-uploads-hidden number" style="display:none;" data-number="1" data-changed="0">
   //cloned data
   </div>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-director">Add Additional Director</button>
```

So, that after that I pass data to controller via ajax, I can get `data-number` of each separate div to be different, so that I can differ them.

How could I do that? Thanks.

Updated:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function clone(){
    var number = $('.director-uploads-hidden').attr('data-number');
       
        var director = $('.director-uploads-hidden').clone(true);
        director.data("number", parseInt(number)+1);
        $('#director-uploads1').append(director);
        director.css("display", "block");
      

    }

    $("button#add-director").on("click", clone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="director-uploads number" id="director-uploads1" data-number="0" data-changed="0">
   //some data
   </div>
 <div class="director-uploads-hidden number" style="display:none;" data-number="1" data-changed="0">
   //cloned data
   </div>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-director">Add Additional Director</button>
```

Thank you all for help, maybe it's not the best solution, but I tried with this and it's working:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function clone(){
   var number = $('#director-uploads1').attr('data-number');
        $("#director-uploads1").attr('data-number', parseInt(number)+1);
        $('.director-uploads-hidden').find('.app-file').attr('data-item', parseInt(number)+1);
        var director = $('.director-uploads-hidden').html();

        $('#director-uploads1').append(director)
            .find("*")
            .each(function() {
                var name = $(this).attr('name');
            })
            .on('click', 'button.clone', clone);
  
   }

    $("button#add-director").on("click", clone);
  
  $("html").on('change', '.app-file', function(){
       var number = $(this).attr('data-item');
        console.log(number);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="director-uploads number" id="director-uploads1" data-number="0" data-changed="0">
 
    <input type="file" class="app-file director_documents" data-item="0" name="director_front_passport[]"/>
    </div>
 <div class="director-uploads-hidden number" style="display:none;" data-number="1" data-changed="0">
    <input type="file" class="app-file director_documents" data-item="0" name="director_front_passport[]"/>
   </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-director">Add Additional Director</button>
```

Comment: I've just created snippet to help you with change the number and id of new cloned div everytime you click on a button

Comment: Thank you, it seems working. You can see how I just made it in my question last snippet. I set `data-item` attribute to each input in div. :)

Comment: yes I can see that, but to make code in a proper way or better query way, you can use my code :)
That will help you to write a long query in a single line.

Comment: Thanks, I will change my code to be more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this snippet.

You can change the attributes and append position as per your need.

```js
//Get old number from the first div
var newNumber = parseInt($('#director-uploads1').attr('data-number'));
$('#add-director').click(function(){
//Get the new length that you would like to set for id
  var newLength = parseInt($('.number').length)+1;
//Increment the old number value with +1 to set the new number for every div.
  newNumber += 1;
  $('div#director-uploads1')
    .clone()
    .attr('id', 'director-uploads'+newLength)
    .attr('data-number', newNumber)
    .removeClass()
    .addClass('director-uploads-hidden number')
    .html('clone data: number'+newNumber +':  id '+' director-uploads'+newLength)
    .insertBefore('#add-director');
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="director-uploads number" id="director-uploads1" data-number="0" data-changed="0">
   //some data
   </div>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-director">Add Additional Director</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `clone` variable won't be holding a clone of `#director-uploads1` it's going to be the collection that `find('*')` creates.

And  `$('.director-uploads-hidden').html()` will only get the inner html, not the outer div tag that holds the data attribute.

To make a clone you would simply use the [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) jQuery method

```
var $clone = $('.director-uploads-hidden').clone();
```

After that to change the data attribute you just set it from `$clone` not `$("#director-uploads1")`

```
$clone.data('number', parseInt(number,10)+1);
//or
$clone.attr('data-number', parseInt(number,10)+1);
```

Also

```
.on('click', 'button.clone', clone);
```

Is trying to set the click handler as your element not your function, because the local variable `clone` is named the same as your function. Rename your clone variable, for instance like `$clone` as in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `clone()` method should help you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var number = parseInt($('#director-uploads1').data('number'));

  function clone(){
    var director = $('.director-uploads-hidden').clone(true); //true will cause it to clone all associated data and events as well
    director.data("number", number+1);
    director.removeClass("director-uploads-hidden");
    director.css("display", "block"); 
    //if you want to add any other extra data or events, do it here before appending the object
    $('#director-uploads1').append(director);
    number++;
  }

  $("button#add-director").on("click", clone);
});
```

See https://api.jquery.com/clone/ for more info on the quirks of this method. You may need to do some more tweaking depending on your precise situation and requirements.

Comment: I tried in this way, but second div with class director-uploads-hidden has style `display:none` and how to clone it and make it visible?

Comment: `director.css("display", "block");`

Comment: I updated my question with current code, but when I click clone first time, it sets data-number = 1 but when I click clone again, it sets again data-number 1. I'm trying to make each div with different data-number, so I can differ them.

Comment: your question specifically says " I want to set newly cloned div with class director-uploads-hidden data-number to be with value #director-uploads1 data-number + 1". That implies it should be the same every time, since #director-uploads1 data-number is always 1 :-) But I'll update with a version that will increment from that value.

Comment: Yes, I havent explained correct. each time, when button is clicked, data-number should be incremented with 1. I want after that to have unique data-number for each div.

Comment: ok it's updated now. number is now collected at page load and stored outside the context of the function, and then incremented each time

Comment: I think clone() is not good option because now when I click clone, it gets content of `.director-uploads-hidden` and when I click it again, it appends this div twice. And each time clone() function is called, it gets ` var number = parseInt($('#director-uploads1').data('number'));` which is always 0 and increments it to 1.

Comment: but you've just said you want it to be able to be clicked multiple times...so what's the problem? And `var number = parseInt($('#director-uploads1').data('number'));` will only be run once, at page load (assuming you've moved it outside the `clone()` function, as per my example). Then `number` will be incremented each time clone() is called. If you are seeing some kind of different behaviour you should describe it in more precise detail.

Comment: Thank you all for help, maybe I didn't explain correct what I expect. Maybe it's not correct solution, but I updated my question and I get proper results now. :)